# How to avoid "the code of method setup() is exceeding 65535" on Processing

Tags: processing

I am completely new to Processing. I am generating Processing code using C, basically a lot of:

```html
stroke(213);
fill(213);
rect(300,260,20,20);
```

I generate the code in a file, and then paste it to Processing. Unfortunately, this gives me an error: "the code of method setup() is exceeding 65535". I understand this is a Java limit, and nothing can be done about it.

Do you have an idea how I can fix this? Please, show me the Processing code, since I know nothing about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing so much in one method, split the work up into multiple methods that you then call from the original method.

```
void setup(){
   setupPartOne();
   setupPartTwo();
   //...
}

void setupPartOne(){
   //do stuff
}

void setupPartTwo(){
   //do stuff
}
```

I'm surprised that answer didn't show up when you googled your error!

Comment: Thanks! Now that I see it, I recognise answers on the web.